# How can I reduce the stack frame of a deeply recursive function in C?

Tags: c, gcc, recursion, stack, callstack

Suppose I have some recursive function that manipulates a graph structure:

```
typedef struct Node {
    Data data;
    size_t visited;
    size_t num_neighbors;
    struct Node *neighbors[];
} Node;

void doSomethingWithNode(Node *node)
{
    if ((!node) || node->visited)
        return;
    node->visited = 1;
    /* Do something with node->data */
    size_t /* some local variables */;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < node->num_neighbors; i++)
    {
        /* Do some calculations with the local variables */
        if (/* something */)
            doSomethingWithNode(node->neighbors[i]);
    }
}
```

Because of the local variables I use in the loop, the compiler (`gcc`) creates a larger-than-I-would-like stack frame for this function (a good number of `pushq` and `popq` instructions even with `-O3`), which is a problem, since it is deeply recursive. Since it doesn't matter what order I visit the nodes in, I could refactor this code to use a stack of `Node` pointers, thus reducing the overhead to one pointer per iteration.

1. Are there any hints I can give the compiler (`gcc`) to fix this problem?
2. If not, is it possible to make use of the call stack itself for my stack of pointers without resorting to assembly?

Comment: All recursive code can also be expressed as non-recursive using loops. You can also increase the stack size when linking (using e.g. the `-z stack-size` [linker option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options)) if the default 8MB (on Linux) is not enough. Though I don't really see the need as the number of local variables is relative small (depending on "some local variables" of course) and without arrays. And the local variables aren't really handled with `push` and `pop` instructions so are you really looking at the correct code?

Comment: After a short look in gcc manual page I see an option -fconserve-stack. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Marian I just tried compiling a programming language implementation with `-fconserve-stack`. It made no difference to the test program which probes the maximum recursion depth: with or without the interpreter compiled with that option, the same number of recursive calls were achieved. No difference in `time make tests` either.  The option has a generic name, but probably targets specific situations that have to arise before it does anything. Perhaps you have to have lots of non-overlapping block scopes in the same function, which can be folded to the same stack space or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

You could maintain a vector or a list (or some queue, or perhaps a stack, or even some arbitrary unordered set) of nodes to be visited (and you probably want to maintain a set or hash table of already visited nodes).

Then you'll have a loop which picks the node in front of the to-be-visited container, and might add some unvisited nodes in the back of that container....

Read the wikipages about [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) and about [tail calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)

Google also for *Deutsch Schorr Waite Algorithm*, it could give you some ideas.

Comment: That's what I meant when I said "I could refactor this code to use a stack".

Comment: Yes, but since, as I said, order doesn't matter, a stack would probably be easier to use.

Comment: But thanks for the suggestion about the Deutsch Schorr Waite Algorithm. That looks like exactly the right thing! Only problem is it seems to assume only two neighbors...

Answer (score 3):

Can you put the calculations into their own, non-recursive function? That way the stack for all the temporary variables will not be there when you make the recursive call.

Update: looks like at least some data in the local variables is essential for recursion. You can use [alloca](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) to explicitly allocate memory on the stack.

Comment: No, their values need to be preserved over iterations of the loop.

Comment: May be two loops? One recursive, one not? `i` is needed on the stack because it's essential for the state of recursion. Are any other variables essential in that way?

Comment: In order to do that, I would need to maintain a list of pointers to then pass to the recursive calls. At that point, I might as well use a loop instead of recursion, and that's exactly what I'm asking about in number 2.

Answer (score 2):

What would you expect the compiler to do in order to solve the problem?

You can of course go through your code, and minimize the number of local variables, try to make it as clear as possible that they are (for instance) only assigned to once by using `const` when possible, and so on. This *might* make the compiler re-use the space, if possible.

Failing that, you can probably save some memory by going iterative instead since that cuts out the need for the return address.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `malloc` and `realloc` to manage a dynamically-growing stack of nodes.  Here's a "class" for managing the stack:

```
typedef struct Stack {
    void **pointers;
    size_t count;
    size_t alloc;
} Stack;

void Stack_new(Stack *stack)
{
    stack->alloc = 10;
    stack->count = 0;
    stack->pointers = malloc(stack->alloc * sizeof(void*));
}

void Stack_free(Stack *stack)
{
    free(stack->pointers);
    stack->pointers = null;
}

void Stack_push(Stack *stack, void *value)
{
    if (stack->alloc < stack->count + 1) {
        stack->alloc *= 2;
        stack->pointers = realloc(stack->pointers, stack->alloc * sizeof(void*));
    }
    stack->pointers[stack->count++] = value;
}

void *Stack_pop(Stack *stack)
{
    if (stack->count > 0)
        return stack->pointers[--stack->count];
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite see how this is related to the local variables in a recursive function?

Comment: Yes, I can. But why not use the call stack if it's possible? That's why I'm asking this.

Comment: @Lundin: I was just helping with storing the stack of pointers outside of the stack, to avoid using the stack for recursion.  But now I see the issue, e.g. 10 variables on the stack for every level of recursion.

Comment: @Lundin It's relevant because a stack data structure can be used as a parallel stack in recursive calls, or even to support an alternative algorithm whose program logic is iterative (or tail recursive) and all the context is in the explicit stack.

Answer (score 2):

"it is deeply recursive" is a hint that the deepest recursions occur in paths that do not have more than 1 non-visited `neighbor`.

Let code only recurse when there is more than 1 interesting neighbor, otherwise just loop.

```
void doSomethingWithNode(Node *node) {
  while (node) {
    if (node->visited) return;
    node->visited = 1;
    /* Do something with node->data */
    size_t /* some local variables */;
    size_t i;
    Node *first = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < node->num_neighbors; i++) {
        /* Do some calculations with the local variables */
        if (/* something */) {

          // Save the first interesting node->neighbors[i] for later
          if (first == NULL && 
              node->neighbors[i] != NULL && 
              node->neighbors[i]->visited == 0) {
            first = node->neighbors[i];

         } else {
            doSomethingWithNode(node->neighbors[i]);
          }
        }
    }
    node = first;
  }
}
```

This does not reduce the stack frame, but eliminate recursion when there is only 1-ply.  IOWs: when recursion is not needed.

The recursion depth should now no longer exceed O(log2(n)) instead of the original worst-case O(n)

Answer (score 1):

If you have more number of local variables and arrays then you can try allocating memory using `malloc`,manipulate it using single pointer and fixed offsets .`free` the memory while exiting from function.

In this way you will save the stack and reuse same heap(maybe) section for all the iterations.

Answer (score 1):

I find many if the other answers not elegant and requiring much overhead. Probably there is no good way and any way depends on the type of recursion at hand.

In your case, the recursion is at the end and only variable i is still needed. To reduce the stack frame, you can use for al other variables global space.

If you want to reduce even more and remove i, you can use node->visisted as a counter:

```
static struct VARS {
    int iSomething;
    Data *dataptr;
    double avg;
} gVars;

void doSomethingWithNode(Node *node)
{
    if ((!node) || node->visited)
        return;
    /* Do something with node->data */
    /* some local variables in global space */;
    gVars.iSomething= 1;
    for (; node->visited < node->num_neighbors; node->visited++)
    {
        /* Do some calculations with the local variables */
        if (/* something */)
            doSomethingWithNode(node->neighbors[node->visited]);
    }
}
```

Comment: p.s.: as this is still a hack, it is not elegant either.

Comment: I don't see how this helps. `i` is not the problem. The problem is the other local variables that I cannot remove from the loop.

Comment: If these local variables in the loop do not carry information over the iterations, then you can move them to global space too. If they do, you could even consider moving them into the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Put all local variables which are not essential for recursion into `struct locals` and access them with `plocals->`. The advantage over putting the calculations into their own, non-recursive function (Arkadiy's answer) is, if needed, that the variables are valid and retain their values over the recursions.

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct Data {
    char data[1];
};

typedef struct Node {
    struct Data data;
    size_t visited;
    size_t num_neighbors;
    struct Node *neighbors;
} Node;

struct Locals {
    /* local variables not essential for recursion */;
};
static void doSomethingWithNodeRecurse(Node *node, struct Locals *plocals)
{
    if ((!node) || node->visited)
        return;
    node->visited = 1;
    /* Do something with node->data */
    /* local variables essential for recursion */
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < node->num_neighbors; i++)
    {
        /* Do some calculations with the local variables */
        if (1/* something */)
            doSomethingWithNodeRecurse(&node->neighbors[i], plocals);
        /* Do some calculations with the local variables */
    }
}

void doSomethingWithNode(Node *node)
{
    struct Locals locals;

    doSomethingWithNodeRecurse(node, &locals);
}
```

If the variables are still too huge to allocate them on the stack, they can be allocated on the heap as Vagish suggested:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Data {
    char data[1];
};

typedef struct Node {
    struct Data data;
    size_t visited;
    size_t num_neighbors;
    struct Node *neighbors;
} Node;

struct Locals {
    /* local variables too big for allocation on stack */;
};
void doSomethingWithNode(Node *node)
{
    struct Locals *plocals;

    if ((!node) || node->visited)
        return;

    /* ---> allocate the variables on the heap <--- */
    if ((plocals = malloc(sizeof *plocals)) == NULL) abort();

    node->visited = 1;
    /* Do something with node->data */
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < node->num_neighbors; i++)
    {
        /* Do some calculations with the local variables */
        if (1/* something */)
            doSomethingWithNode(&node->neighbors[i]);
        /* Do some calculations with the local variables */
    }
    /* ---> free the variables <--- */
    free(plocals);
}
```